# gnuplot smooth bezier produces straight line segments

Tags: gnuplot, bezier, smoothing

I run gnuplot 5.0 on Windows 7.
I have a datafile with columns with 1000 lines. I want to gnuplot the 2nd column vs. the first and smooth the curve:

plot "data.dat" u 1 : 2   t "total bez"  smooth bezier

The result looks overall reasonable, BUT: The problem is that this produces 3 straight line segments at small values of the x-axis; the higher values are smoothed out allright.

I experimented with this problem: by cutting the file to have less lines in it the plot becomes smooth also at lower x. Is there a limitation on the number of points that gnuplot smooth bezier can handle?
U.

Comment: This is a good question for the gnuplot e-mail list if no one can answer it here.

Comment: Its hard to tell if this a bug, without having some test data and the output file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set samples to higher value, for example

```
set samples 10000 
plot "data.dat" u 1 : 2 t "total bez" smooth bezier
```

From gnuplot help:

> By default, sampling is set to 100 points.  A higher sampling rate will
>    produce more accurate plots, but will take longer.  This parameter has no
>    effect on data file plotting unless one of the interpolation/approximation
>    options is used.  See `plot smooth` re 2D data and `set cntrparam` and
>    `set dgrid3d` re 3D data.